# BoxLayout Will not print vertically using the PAGE_AXIS or Y_AXIS orientation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, boxlayout

I cannot seem to find a solution as to why I cannot get a set of JButtons to print vertically using the BoxLayout manager. my code is as follows:

```
    right_Panel = new JPanel();
    right_Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(right_Panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    right_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 200));

    boom = new JButton("BOOM");
    boom.addActionListener(this);


    keyLabel = new JButton[4];

    JButton[] keyColor = { new JButton("Green: 0 mines"), new JButton("Yellow: 1 mine"),
            new JButton("Orange: 2 mines"), new JButton("Red: 3 mines"), new JButton("Pink: 4 mines") };
    keyLabel = keyColor;

    right_Panel = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < keyLabel.length; i++) {
        keyLabel[i].setBackground(colorKey[i]);
        right_Panel.add(keyLabel[i]);
    }
    boom.setBackground(colorKey[5]);

    right_Panel.add(boom);
```

I feel like I'm just making a stupid mistake, I have similar code working for vertical orientation in a separate part of my program, but I can't figure this part out. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: thank you for the advice, I found the solution so I will not edit it. I had simply declared my panel two times, one of which was after the formatting which wiped the formatting clean.